# I accidentally chmodded the file system root - how can I revert this?

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, chmod

I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

I mistyped and wrote `sudo chmod 444 /` instead of writing `/home`.

Everything went blank and icons started disappearing, and now when I try to run Ubuntu, it hangs on the initial Ubuntu sign.

I know that I have changed the permissions for root itself, but is there any way I can revert back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've only chmod'ed you root directory:

In linux, use `chmod 755` to restore correct root directory access rights.

In Mac OS X, the sticky bit must be set, too. Use `chmod +t /` if you've already corrected the rights to 755. If not, you can do both at once using `chmod 1755 /`.

For both systems: Don't forget sudo if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Entered this in the root prompt and everything got recovered ....

Comment: Did chmod / once for educational reasons and took me quite some while to figure out the sticky but stuff. :)

Comment: -1, `/` is *not* supposed to have the sticky bit set. It's only for `/tmp`.

Comment: @grawity Looks you're right, it isn't set on my linux boxes either. You need it on OS X machines, I misconcieved this would be the same in linux. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Interesting. I'm curious why OS X uses it...

Comment: @grawity: it's because OS X allows the admin group write access to /, and without the sticky bit an admin could do nasty things like rename & replace top-level dirs without needing to go through any special authentication (sudo or the like).

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to boot into single user mode/rescue mode at the initial grub bootloader
If that doesn't work you can use an ubuntu or other boot disk such as [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) to boot your system, mount the / fs and correct it.
This is assume you did `chmod 444 /` not `chmod -R 444 /`

Comment: Good call on the recursion switch... let's hope you're right.

Comment: how do i boot in the rescue mode ? And yes i did did the first one not the second

Comment: Can you still get to a shell at all? Do you still have one open?

Comment: Okayz things have changed ... went into recovery mode and then clicked on drop to root shell prompt ... Can you tell me what should i now enter to correct everything ?

Comment: root is normally 755, so if you can do chmod 755 / that should restore it to a normal state